# How to save dataset with missing values after identifying it in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I have checked my data for missing values using pandas, and I get to realize that some of them are caused by errors during data entry. Now I want to send back the list of missing values to the users to refill them, but I can't figure out how to save that list with the missing values only!
Could someone help me figure out how to extract that particular list only?
Thank you

The code line is;

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9TdD.png)

So, now I want to save the data with missing values only without including those with values.

Comment: There's not enough detail in this question to provide a code suggestion. How are you finding the missing values? Can you provide an example of how you're getting the list you'd like to send back to your users?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a data set, df.  and I check for the number of null values in each column in this manner;

df.isnull().sum()

So now, I need to save only those with missing values so that I sent back to the users for correction

Comment: Anyone to help me answer this, please.....